# How to get max date (Future) from an object array swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, iphone, max

This is my object, where I want to get the highest `expiresDate`.

```
struct LatestReceiptInfo {
    var productId: String?
    var expiresDate: Date? = nil
    var isInIntroOffer_period: Bool?
    var isTrialPeriod: Bool?
    var cancellationDate: Date? = nil
}
```

`latestReceiptInfoArray` is my array.

```
for latestReceiptInfo in latestReceiptInfoArray {
    //2. Get the highest expire_date from latestInfoReceiptObjects array
    if let exDate = latestReceiptInfo.expiresDate {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `min()` to do that: `let oldestDate = recipes.min(by: { $0.expiresDate ?? Date() < $1.expiresDate ?? Date() })` might do the trick, or something like that to test.

Comment: I am getting this with this code: `highestExpireDate Optional(InAppPurchasePT.IAPManager.LatestReceiptInfo(productId: Optional("com.apollo.InAppPurchasePT.AutoRenewableGroup.ARenewable1"), expiresDate: Optional(2022-02-16 13:42:21 +0000), isInIntroOffer_period: Optional(false), isTrialPeriod: Optional(true), cancellationDate: nil))`

Comment: Sorry, it's `oldestrRecipe`, not `latestDate`, `let oldestDate = recipes.max(by: { $0.expiresDate ?? Date() < $1.expiresDate ?? Date() })?.expiresDate` (sorry, O also understood oldest instead of latest). I guess it might work now. If not, replace `<` with `>`?

Comment: are you only looking for the actual highest date? Or the LatestReceiptInfo _with_ the highest date?

Comment: @fguchelaar The highest date in that array `latestReceiptInfoArray`. Thanks!

Comment: @Larme Can you post it as an answer. I want to accept it as the answer of this post. Thanks a lot for your

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only looking for the date, instead of the LatestReceiptInfo *with* the highest date, than you could `compactMap` the dates (takes out nil-values) and then get the highest one with the `max` function.

```swift
let highestDate = latestReceiptInfoArray
    .compactMap { $0.expiresDate }
    .max()
```

If you want to get the LatestReceiptInfo with the highest date, various approaches will do the trick. For instance by filtering all values that actually have a date. After that you can force-unwrap (yugh) the date in the comparison.

```swift
let highestReceiptInfo = latestReceiptInfoArray
    .filter { $0.expiresDate != nil }
    .max { $0.expiresDate! < $1.expiresDate! }
```

Comment: I am using `.compactMap { $0.expiresDate }`. The same result. Xcode is saying that `.flatMap` is deprecated.

Comment: Just wondering if I want to get the object as well, which contains that highest date. How could I do that?

Comment: There's always will be a expire date. So I think it's ok to force unwrap it. :)

Comment: if there will always be an `expiresDate`, then I would suggest to not declare it as nullable in your Struct, then you won't need to unwrap it.

Comment: Why not simply `let highestReceiptInfo = latestReceiptInfoArray.max { $0.expiresDate ?? .distantPast < $1.expiresDate ?? .distantPast }`?

Comment: That could result in a value, where the date is `nil`, if all of the receipts have a `nil` date. That **might** be what you want, but maybe not.